# Bash script to create symlinks

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, symlink

I am trying to create a script which would create symlinks from a folder 1 level up and i am using as follows:

symlinks.sh

```
ln -s '../config/environments' > 'environments'
ln -s '../config/init' > 'init'
```

environments is a folder and init is a file.

and when i go to the folder where symlinks.sh is and execute ./symlinks.sh, its creating 4 files which are:

1. environments
2. environments?
3. init
4. init?

I also tried:

```
ln -s '../config/environments' .
ln -s '../config/init' .
```

but with this one, init is created in the current folder and environments goes to folder ../config/environments/environments

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are redirecting the output ">". You don't need to do that with ln, it will automatically create a symlink in the current directory if you use:

```
ln -s "../config/environments" 
ln -s "../config/init"
```

Comment: i did try this too but i didnt mention. The result for this gave me environments? and init? in the same folder. i just tried it again and the same result. why is there the '?' at the end? fyi: im using putty and when i 'ls' in the directory the 2 files created are red in colour.

Comment: @user2707590 Does `../config/environments` exist? What does `ls -l environments` say? What do `stat environments` and `stat -L environments` say?

Comment: all 3 commands tell me No such file or directory, and yes ../config/environments does exist

Comment: ok i think i got it... was a bad mistake from me :(. the .sh file was created in windows and i deleted it and recreated in my ubuntu and its working... 
thanks guys :)